# Some WiFi networks missing since windows 10 upgrade

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

Ever since the upgrade from windows 7 to windows 10, some of the WiFi networks I was previously able to connect to have gone missing (not all of them, though).

I have tried the solution offered [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3084164), which did not work.

I have also updated the driver to my Wifi card (D-Link DWA-548), but it didn't help either.

Any help you might offer me would be greatly appreciated.

Update: I changed the channel of the network, from 13 to 1 - and now I can see and connect to it on my PC. However, this means that I am getting a much worse service, so I am still on the lookout for better solutions.

Update #2: turns out, Windows decided it doesn't want to see networks on channels higher than 11. [This page](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d3c9ca96-92fd-452d-b64d-55e9bb619fd4/cant-connect-to-wifi-on-channel-13-after-windows-update-multiple-different-computers-affected?forum=w7itpronetworking) describes how to change it.

Comment: If you could "see" them before and not now, find out if the missing ones are 5Ghz or not.

Comment: the missing networks are 2.4G (every other WiFi-able machine in my house can still see these networks).

Comment: Can you determine anything the missing ones have in common?

Comment: Sadly, no. tbh, I only care about my home network. The other networks I am seeing and missing all belong to other people living in my apartment building.

Comment: From an elevated(admin) cmd prompt run:  netsh wlan delete profile name=* i=*

Comment: This will make windows forget all wifi networks and give you a clean slate in case theres a bad profile stuck in there.

Comment: I did that, should I expect any change?

Comment: Just reboot and let it hunt of beacons again

Comment: Sadly, this did nothing

Comment: Your update shows that its just a region setting. Some countries are 1-11 and some are 1-13. The adapter properties will allow you to change region most likely re-enabling CH12&13.

Comment: My router lets me go all the way to 13, though my PC can see up to 11 (before the upgrade to windows 10 it could see 12 and 13). Is there a way to make it see those higher channels?

Comment: Its driver/OEM dependant. You need to find out where the setting is for whoever manufacturers your adapter. The setting isnt obvious on my intel adapter.

Comment: Finally fixed. Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: And how did you fix it?

Comment: I had similar problem on Win 10 after update. Windows doesn't show my network name on networks list. Other networks were available. I fixed it by changing property **Country Region** in advanced setting of WiFi Card. I set it to value '#1 (1-13)'. Before changed value was '#0 (1-11)'.

Answer (score 0):

My adapter properties did not allow me to change the country region, but I fixed it by changing the channel width (2,4 Ghz) from "Auto" to 20 MHz.